# Is it possible for a word not to exist?

Tags: meaning

I was corrected that funner is not a word. After [looking into it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137907/is-funner-a-word), it seems that it is a word in the sense that it is frequently used and people know what it means. Since a word is a sound with an associated meaning, can one ever conclusively say anything is not a word? If no, then what can be said about words such as "hommie" or "dethaw" (or "bestester").

Comment: This has certainly been covered here before (though people's definitions of 'word' differ/ed markedly, making discussion problematic). If two people use a 'sound / written representation thereof with an associated meaning agreed upon only by themselves' should that be classed as a word? 10 people? How many? Do we have to wait until it appears in OED? UD?

Comment: _Scrumpfle_ and _Plamf_ are two of my favourite 'words', and must have been in reasonably common use in Scotland for me to pick them up because I'm sure that's where I heard them but they are not to be found in any [nominal](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184876/) dictionary (except UrbanDictionary).